# Issue with Twitter Lists not displaying correct tweets

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, widget

Twitter Lists are not working?

- My client has made a list with the people that he wants to show tweet's from.
- List can be viewed here: https://twitter.com/Leidsverzet/top
- It contains 5 persons.

The  embedding works correctly but I am experiencing something really strange: **Not all the tweets from these 5 persons are displayed**!!!

In order to test further I made a [single person test list] with only one person to to test. That list works correctly except that **it does not display that user's replies**.

I am understanding something wrong here? Aren't [twitter lists](https://support.twitter.com/articles/76460-how-to-use-twitter-lists) something like **groups**, where you can put people like family or prof connections and just see their timelines?

A small footer note on why I wan't to use lists is because the twitter search plugin is not working correctly as well, so instead of using search queries I had trust that the lists would do the trick, but apparently not. Or twitter search feeds and list's are not good or I am lost somewhere here.

Comment: Twitter would only show the tweets that are sent in the last one week. For example  @CFLeiden user sent only 3 messages in the last one week, so you would only see those 3 messages. But if you don't even see those results then something else might be wrong with widget.

Comment: You can check the links @cubbuk. It's not howling anything from that user. That is my point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contacted Twitter and issue is solved.

*take care*

These list might also have been corrected by time eg(crawling time etc)

Comment: I have no idea as Twitter support provides little information. 
The Lists right now have the correct content. I don't know what was causing the problem. Lost in the unknown.

Comment: im having the same problem, this is crazy / the whole world uses twitter thinking their lists are working alright, but they actually dont display all the content

Comment: @fartagaintuxedo wait some time. If not open a ticket.

Comment: i stopped using lists, also because i dont get tweets that are retweeted from people on my list, which is kind of pointless i would say

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add that I found this while looking for solutions to my own list problem, and one thing that resolved my issue was to edit the list, delete the person whose tweets are not getting displayed, and then add them back.